# Odd duplicate event handlers

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, event-handling, ms-office, office-js

(I simplify a question that I asked previously...)

In my Excel Online add-in, I want to set up a toggle. When it is turned on, it activates a event handler that listens to the selection change of the workbook; when it is turned off, it deactivates the event handler.

The following is the JavaScript code. What I expect is: when the toggle is on, each time i click on a new cell of the workbook, it adds **one** `Done!`; when the toggle is off, nothing will be printed while clicking new cells.

```
(function() {
    "use strict";

    Office.initialize = function(reason) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            app.initialize();            
            $('#toggle').click(handleClick);
        });
    };

    function handleClick() {
        if ($('#toggle').prop("checked")) 
        {
            Office.context.document.addHandlerAsync(Office.EventType.DocumentSelectionChanged, MyHandler);
        } else 
        {
            Office.context.document.removeHandlerAsync(Office.EventType.DocumentSelectionChanged, {
            handler: MyHandler
        });
        }
    }

    function MyHandler(eventArgs) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += "Done!"
    }
})();
```

When I test the code, the first time the toggle is turned on, it adds **one** `Done!` after selecting each new cell. However, when the toggle is turned on => off => on, it adds **two** `Done!` after selecting each new cell. when the toggle is turned on => off => on => off => on, it adds **three** `Done!` after selecting each new cell... It is really wired...

Does anyone know what is happening?

PS: Here is [Home.html](http://pastebin.com/x4c9SH6D).

PS2: I have also written a [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/pidize/6/edit?html,js,output) with a similar structure, `document.addEventListener` and `document.removeEventListener`. They don't have this problem...

Comment: Where are you seeing this issue?  I just tried to repro it using Excel 2016, and am NOT seeing this issue.  Are you using Excel Online?  Or Excel 2013?...

Comment: Yes, I am using Excel Online...

Comment: I just tested it with Excel 2016, this issue does not exist... So it is a problem of Excel Online?

Comment: @MichaelZlatkovsky did you succeed in reproducing this problem with Excel Online? If it is a bug, do you have any workaround?

Comment: we have reproduced the issue and have a fix, which should roll out to Excel Online in a few weeks.

Comment: Thanks for coming back... I am glad to have contributed to that...